# solid state relay design with overcurrent protection

Tags: microcontroller, altium, opto-isolator, protection, solid-state-relay

I designed a [solid state relay](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-F5BHwIwpwKd1p0cUVFQm9XVFE) circuit whose input controlled by [lpc43s50fet256](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC43S50_30_20.pdf) microprocessor .I use [ltc1154](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1154fc.pdf) overcurrent protection driver to close SSR when load current is bigger than  30 A.İf load current is bigger than 30A ,Status pin of the ltc1154 will send a output to the microprocessor and microprocessor will close this relay.I wonder whether my design has any mistake or not.

Comment: I've read your question twice and looked at the schematic and I am not sure what you are trying to do. (1) Why have you got an opto-isolator? (2) The LTC1154 is a high-side MOSFET gate driver. Where is the positive supply for the load? Your MOSFET seems to be in backwards. (3) Try to reorganise your schematic with positive rails on top and current flowing to bottom of page as is normal practice. Follow the layout in the LTC datasheet to make comparison easier. This will make it much easier to follow.

Comment: I didn't connect any Voltage source because it is not important .What I want to do is to make a solid state relay switch controlled by microprocessor to choose which one is open or close  ( I/O ) and if there is an overcurrent , voltage must be cut. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Of course the voltage source is important! How can the reader know which way the current flows? "*What is your suggestion?*" I have already given my suggestions. I gave you three questions. I numbered them so you couldn't forget to answer one. You have only half-answered number 2 (and that answer is no good). The rest of your comment is repeating what is in your post.

Comment: I understood what you want to say. Thanks for your corrections and  suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be correct.According to datasheet ,resistor value must be 0.06 .You inverted the microprocessor output because the enable  pin requires reverse voltage .In and Enable  pin connections are true  .In addition you connected 51k resistor with Vcc  on the output .Therefore I think this is excellent.

Comment: You  didn't give me a good answer but , I will accept you answer.